# Opening a Url from OnClickListener Android

Tags: java, android, url, webview, onclicklistener

I am trying to open up a webpage from an a button in Android but can't quite get it to work. I found a tutorial that seemed pretty straightforward but the trick is that I'm trying to display a url that was taken from an object created in another activity class. The code I'm using is a standard OnClickListener:

```
private void addListeneronButton() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stationHistory);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

          Intent browserIntent = 
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(//need help here));
            startActivity(browserIntent);

        }
```

The project is reading a list of weather stations. I have a Station class with appropriate getters/setters so the Url is already stored. I just don't know the appropriate command to access from here. I thought it would be as easy as Uri.parse(station.get_url) but that then it just prompts me create local variable...Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
<station>
    <station_id>NFNA</station_id>
    <state>FJ</state>
    <station_name>Nausori</station_name>
    <latitude>-18.05</latitude>
    <longitude>178.567</longitude>
    <html_url>http://weather.noaa.gov/weather/current/NFNA.html</html_url>
    <rss_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/NFNA.rss</rss_url>
    <xml_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/NFNA.xml</xml_url>
</station>

<station>
    <station_id>KCEW</station_id>
    <state>FL</state>
            <station_name>Crestview, Sikes Airport</station_name>
    <latitude>30.79</latitude>
    <longitude>-86.52</longitude>
            <html_url>http://weather.noaa.gov/weather/current/KCEW.html</html_url>
            <rss_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KCEW.rss</rss_url>
            <xml_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KCEW.xml</xml_url>
</station>

<station>
    <station_id>KDTS</station_id>
    <state>FL</state>
            <station_name>Destin, Ft. Walton Beach Airport</station_name>
    <latitude>30.4</latitude>
    <longitude>-86.47</longitude>
            <html_url>http://weather.noaa.gov/weather/current/KDTS.html</html_url>
            <rss_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KDTS.rss</rss_url>
            <xml_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KDTS.xml</xml_url>
</station>
```

I'm parsing these into a Station Class with constructors/getters/setters. From a previous Activity, the user selects one of these stations. On the next activity it displays name, id, etc elements from this xml. But now I want to open the stations url from a button and I'm not sure how.

Comment: Paste the URL, note that you need to include `http://` or `https://` in your Uri.parse

Comment: a sample url would be: http://weather.noaa.gov/weather/current/NFNA.html

Comment: So try putting `http://` before that: `http://http://weather.noaa.gov/weather/current/NFNA.html`

Comment: But I'm getting these from an example as posted above.

Comment: I don't know why this wouldn't work but have you tried creating a variable like `Uri uri = http:// weather.noaa.gov/weather/current/NFNA.html` then put that in your `Intent`?

Comment: Thanks I guess I should have explained a little better. Edited my code above.

Comment: So get the `String` Url` from the `getter` and add it to a local variable then add that to your `Intent`. You said you already have it stored. Where/how is it stored?

Comment: I have class called Station.Java. I create a station object inside my OnCreate method. I'm trying create a local variable with = to station.getUrl but I'm not sure where. It's not working from onclicklistener or oncreate.

Comment: Then post how you are trying to get it from `onCreate()` and the method in your `Station class` in which you have it. Also, describe what isn't working. Getting an error, returning nothing, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think I see what you are saying is the problem now, although you really didn't make it very clear. You have this

```
private void addListeneronButton() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stationHistory);

button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

      Intent browserIntent = 
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(station.get_url);
        startActivity(browserIntent);

    }
```

and it is telling you that `station.get_url` is not a variable so you need to create one. `get_url` should be `get_url()` if it is a method. If your class is `Station` (capital "S") then you would access it with `Station.get_url()`. However, you may need to pass in a certain parameter to tell it which url to get. This is assuming it is a `static` method. If it is not then you need to create an instance of the `Station` class and call the method

```
Station myStation = new Station();  //pass parameters here to constructor as needed
String address = myStation.get_url();  // object
```

Then you can use `address` in your `Intent`.

```
 Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(address));
 startActivity(browserIntent);
```

If `http://` isn't passed back with the url then it will have to be appended before using it in the `Intent`, as wangyif2 has already stated. I hope this makes sense but its the best I can do with the information given.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting http:// before the string when you do your URI parsing:

```
private void addListeneronButton() {
   button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stationHistory);
   button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
           Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
             Uri.parse(Station.getHtmlUrl("NFNA"));
           startActivity(browserIntent);
       }
}
```

Station class:

```
public static String getHtmlUrl(String station) { 
    //return the full URL here based on station 
    //eg. "http://weather.noaa.gov/weather/current/NFNA.html"
}
```

Comment: Check again, is that what you want?